# recode values in a character variable based on another character variable's value in sas

Tags: string, sas, recode

`jrnlfile` is a dataset with journal names and identifiers. Here are the first 6 obs:

```
id      journal                         issn
56201   ACTA HAEMATOLOGICA              0001-5792
94365   ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA  
10334   ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA      1671-4083
55123   ADVANCES IN ENZYME REGULATION   0065-2571
90002   AGING   
10403   AGING                           1945-4589
```

Compare `id` 94365 and 10334. These obs name the same `journal`. They need the same `issn`. An obs with a missing value for `issn` *almost always* has at least one partner obs that contains a matching `journal` name and the correct `issn`. Wherever this is true, I want to recode the missing `issn` so it contains the `issn` seen in other instances where the same `journal` is mentioned. A revised dataset `want` would look like this:

```
id      journal                         issn
56201   ACTA HAEMATOLOGICA              0001-5792
94365   ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA      1671-4083
10334   ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA      1671-4083
55123   ADVANCES IN ENZYME REGULATION   0065-2571
90002   AGING                           1945-4589
10403   AGING                           1945-4589
```

I currently use if-else statements in a data step to populate missing `issn` values with matching entries for `journal`:

```
data want;
    set jrnlfile;
         if journal = "ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA" then issn = "1671-4083";
    else if journal = "AGING"                      then issn = "1945-4589";
    /*continue for 7,000 other journals*/
    run;
```

But `jrnlfile` contains 50,000 obs and 7,000 unique journals, so this takes a lot of time and is rather error-prone. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52748924/sas-reverse-order-of-values-of-a-variable-based-on-another-variable-value-in-a) gets me halfway there, but `issn` is not numeric and I can't solve the problem by simply adding values to it.

What is a more efficient and systematic way to get to `want` from `jrnlfile`?

Comment: Can you sort the dataset by journal  in a way that the value you want to use for ISSN is on the first observation for that journal?   `by journal descending issn;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use retain statment. But there is restraints for this code. To empty journal will be set the first found issn. And there are must be a one or more issn for journal group.

```
proc sort data=JRNLFILE;
    by journal descending issn;
run;

data want;
    set  JRNLFILE;
    retain t_issn;
    by journal descending issn;

    if first.journal then
        do;
            if issn="" then do;
                put "ERROR: there is no issn val for group";
                stop;
            end;
            else t_issn =issn;
        end;

    if issn="" then
        do;
            issn=t_issn;
        end;
run;
```

For example. If you use this table:

```
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
|  id   |           journal            |    issn   |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
| 94365 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   |           |
| 10334 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   | 1671-4083 |
|     1 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   | A_TEST    |
|     2 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   | WAS       |
|     3 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   | SATRTED   |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
```

You will get:

```
+-------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
|  id   |          journal           |   issn    | t_issn |
+-------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
|     2 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA | WAS       | WAS    |
|     3 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA | SATRTED   | WAS    |
|     1 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA | A_TEST    | WAS    |
| 10334 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA | 1671-4083 | WAS    |
| 94365 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA | WAS       | WAS    |
+-------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
```

Error example.
If you use this table:

```
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
|  id   |           journal            |    issn   |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
| 56201 | ACTA HAEMATOLOGICA           | 0001-5792 |
| 94365 | ACTA PHARMACOLOGICA SINICA   |           |
+-------+------------------------------+-----------+
```

You will get an ERROR:

> ERROR: there is no issn val for group

*t_issn leaved to understand function :))

Answer (score 1):

If the data is sorted by JOURNAL and the valid value appears first then a simple UPDATE might work.  But watch out if there are other variables with missing values.

```
data want;
  update have(obs=0) have ;
  by journal;
  output;
run;
```

You might try merging the data with the non-missing values of ISSN. That only requires that the data is sorted by JOURNAL. That will work very well if only one unique non-missing value is present.  If there are multiple non-missing values then the results are not so nice.

```
data want ;
   merge have have(where=(not missing(issn)) keep=journal issn rename=(issn=_2));
   by journal;
   if missing(issn) then issn=_2;
   drop _2;
run;
```